# Perl object threading

Tags: multithreading, perl, object, data-structures

Hey all, I have a question about perl objects and threading.

My program is a log parser that processes each line of the logs into an object list, and 
thus, each of the objects can be referenced like this :

**to get the value stored :**

```
print @object[$index]->time;

output : 01:11:22
```

**to set the value :**

```
@object[$index]->time("01:22:25");
print @object[$index]->time;

output : 01:22:25
```

And after saving all of the logs into memory, I will have a list of @objects.

So the problem lies in the processing of the objects.

I want to process the data via threads and I am able to do it on normal data like modifying a string, adding a total, etc.
But I do not know how to do so for objects.

I want to do something like

```
my $thr2 = threads->new(\&processTime, @object);
```

(example is not correct, just an idea of how I want the processing to be)

So therefore I require the help of you guys to help me with the processing of objects via threads. Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to process the data via threads?

Comment: I will have many different processing modules/subs that I wish to have them run concurrently, and some of the logs may also be very long. It is also an experiment on my part with looking at the timing for threading and sequential processing.
The modules will also be some sort of a plugin sub, so after I have written a new processing algorithm, I just have to plug it into a new thread and run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is concurrent processing, there are far fewer problems with forking instead of using threads.  One popular forking library is [Parallel::ForkManager](http://p3rl.org/Parallel%3a%3aForkManager), though there ar e others.

If you feel you must use threads, see [Thread::Queue](http://p3rl.org/Thread%3a%3aQueue) but note its advice to carefully read the threads::shared bugs and limitations section, and particularly read the [example of a share-safe class](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JDHEDDEN/threads-shared-1.36/examples/class.pl).

Also, in perl5, an array element is accessed as `$object[$index]`, not `@object[$index]`; the latter is an array slice, which will work the same in many circumstances, but is less efficient.  If you have warnings enabled (which you should), you should be seeing a warning about this.

Comment: but can i know the difference between Thread::Queue and normal sequential processes as when you queue a process, it still requires the previous process to finish? am i right? or is it a misunderstanding

Comment: @robobooga: you have one or more threads using enqueue to add to the queue, and one or more threads using dequeue or dequeue_nb processing things from the queue, in parallel

Answer (score 0):

IIRC perl does copy-on-write on any object (ref) used by multiple threads unless the object is explicitly marked for sharing. Read the threads::shared perldoc page.

Comment: in the threads::shared page, they have this # Cannot directly rebless the inner object18. #bless($foo->{'bar'}, 'Yang'); 

Does this mean that in my sub, I cannot set the value 
@object[$index]->time("01:22:25"); 

in this manner?